# Difference between -ている and こと•の

Tags: meaning

So i am a bit confused. I am learning japanese and i dont really understand the difference between the two mentioned above.

飲んでいる means drinking right?

飲むこと also means drinking right?

Does it have the same meaning if i say

お酒を飲んでいる

and

お酒を飲むこと

If not, whats the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

飲んでいる describes what you are doing right now. It's a verb form. お酒を飲んでいる means "I'm drinking alcohol".

飲むこと is very different. It's just confusing that English happens to use the same word for both. 飲むこと is the act of drinking. It is a noun form. I'm not very good with English grammar (despite being English) but I think this is called a gerund.

If you want to say something like "I like drinking" then 'drinking' in this sentence works like a noun (compare with 'I like cats'). This hasn't got anything to do with what you are doing right now. This is where 飲むこと is useful. You'd say 飲むことが好きです。

Note that お酒**の**を飲むこと is ungrammatical. I don't know if the の was just a typo, but it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Edited typo, thanks

Comment: @Farsis I should also have mentioned that adding こと or の in this way is called 'nominalization'. It might be worth looking up that phrase to find out more.